# RelayCommand constructor parameter vs field

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I stumbled upon really weird problem with RelayCommand. Compare those two code snippets:

Snippet 1:

```
public RimfirePistolResultsViewModel(Database db, IApplicationSettingsService applicationSettingsService, Router router)
    : base(db, db.RimfirePistolResults, applicationSettingsService)
{
    _router = router;

    ClarifyResultCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(id =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Id: " + id);
            router.Go<ClarifyRimfirePistolView>(new { Id = id });
        });              
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
public RimfirePistolResultsViewModel(Database db, IApplicationSettingsService applicationSettingsService, Router router)
    : base(db, db.RimfirePistolResults, applicationSettingsService)
{
    _router = router;

    ClarifyResultCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(id =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Id: " + id);
            _router.Go<ClarifyRimfirePistolView>(new { Id = id });
        });              
}
```

The only difference between Snippet 1 and 2 is that in first one I call Router instance passed as constructor parameter and in second one assigned to field. When I bind command to button in DataGrid first solution doesn't work when second works with no problems. I thought that since C# has closures both should work fine. Could someone explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the variable scope.
Snippet 1: You are using the variable passed to through the constructor but the scope of the variable is within the constructor. You are using the variable in anonymous delegate which will get executed when the Command is called. In the anonymous delegate your variable will not be in scope.
Snippet 2: Since you are assigning the variable to a field in the class, it will have the scope throughout the class and hence it will be good to use the variable in the anonymous delegate.
Hope it is clear.